# How to display string representation of a context object in Jinja2?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, jinja2

I have a property on a model:

```
@property
def model_name(self):
    """Return the model name."""
    return self._meta.verbose_name
```

In Django templates I display this simply by passing `context['model_attr'] = self.model` and then displaying `{{ model_attr.model_name }}` in the template.

However in Jinja2 this results in `<property object at 0x7f789aba52c0>`. How do I display the `str` representation of the object?

Comment: @VorsprungdurchTechnik unfortunately `@property` is not callable

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: ah, thanks. Deleted comment, and upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to make a *class* property here, for example by implementing this in the metatype:

```
from django.db import models

class NamedModelMeta(type(models.Model)):

    @property
    def model_name(cls):
        """Return the model name."""
        return cls._meta.verbose_name
```

Then we can use this metaclass:

```
class MyModel(models.Model, metaclass=NamedModelMeta):
    # …
```

Comment: thanks through iteration I discovered I can remove `@property` and use `{{ model_attr.model_name(model_attr) }}` is this approach incorrect?

Comment: @alias51: well it does not look very elegant to pass the class object if it already exists. Perhaps you can make it a `@classmethod` instead.